# Error installing nginx with passenger-install-nginx-module on ubuntu 11.10 & rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

Here is the error message from installing nginx with passenger-install-
nginx-module (rvmsudo). The nginx is 1.0.6 installed under /opt/nginx (default). gem install passenger successfully prior.

Someone has idea about the problem? thanks.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/
ext/nginx/../common/libpassenger_common.a(aggregate.o): undefined
reference to symbol 'round@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'round@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/gcc/
x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so so try adding
it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so:
could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/root-passenger-2135/nginx-1.0.6'
make: *** [build] Error 2
--------------------------------------------

It looks like something went wrong
```

......

Answer (score 0):

Passenger downloads header files and links itself to particular libraries that the version of Ubuntu that you are trying to use doesn't have. For the best results try using an LTS distro.

Comment: I am new to the process. Is there a guide I can follow? Thanks.

Comment: There are quite a few guides out there, if you search for `nginx passenger install` or ask on server fault rather than on here.

Comment: ubuntu 11.10 was released last month. Is it LTS distro?

Comment: I think the next one will be, but only last month is too early for a server distro as passenger won't have been tested on it properly.

Answer (score 0):

From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/OW-NDvlWLno

```
 hey! I solve this issue moving block:

 ngx_feature="Math library" ngx_feature_name= ngx_feature_run=no
 ngx_feature_incs="#include <math.h>" ngx_feature_path=
 ngx_feature_libs="-lm" ngx_feature_test="pow(1, 2)"  . auto/feature if
 [ $ngx_found = yes ]; then
     CORE_LIBS="$CORE_LIBS -lm" fi

 to after:

 ngx_addon_name=ngx_http_passenger_module HTTP_MODULES="$HTTP_MODULES
 ngx_http_passenger_module" NGX_ADDON_SRCS="$NGX_ADDON_SRCS \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/ngx_http_passenger_module.c \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/Configuration.c \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/ContentHandler.c \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/StaticContentHandler.c" NGX_ADDON_DEPS="$NGX_ADDON_DEPS \   
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/Configuration.h \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/ContentHandler.h \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/StaticContentHandler.h \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/ngx_http_passenger_module.h \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/../common/Constants.h" CORE_LIBS="$CORE_LIBS  \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/../common/libpassenger_common.a \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/../common/libboost_oxt.a \
     -lstdc++ -lpthread"

 in ext/nginx/config
```